# SQL Server instance is stopped on Windows 8 and not getting started

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed an application which creates SQL Server 2008 instance for its usage. The software and server and not communicating. Actually software is unable to connect to instance.

In the investigation I have found that the SQL Server instance created by software is stopped. I tried to start the SQL service through configuration manager but it is not getting started. I am unsure whether SQL Server 2008 express is compatible with Windows 8. Please help.

Comment: Du you run Skype? It sometimes decides to open ports which conflict with my SQL Server instance.

Comment: If you cannot start the SQL service via SCM, then you need to troubleshoot by looking at the event logs.  You may want to look at the installation logs as well, there is a good chance the install failed.